# Place a logo at rdlc report so that it can update its position dynamically at the top of last column

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working at a rdlc report and i want to Place a logo at the right most corner of the last column.
[image]

I placed it at fixed position at the top of last column. but when in a case a column hides in between than last column moves toward left but logo will remain at the same place and it creates a logo formatting issue.

[image]

please suggest an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have fallen foul of the inability of Reporting services to dynamically alter the location of items.  It is not possible for you to automatically align this logo - without embedding it as part of a table.  There are two ways around this problem.

**Option 1**

Add a new header row to your table.  Merge the cells together.  Insert a rectangle into it, and insert your logo on to this, as shown

[image]

The downside of this is when you hide a column, the last column expands to fill the new whitespace.

[image]

**Option 2**

Add a new header row to your table.  Insert a rectangle into the furthest right column, and insert your logo on to this, as shown.

[image]

Notice how the logo moves with the columns

[image]
(4 columns visible)

[image]
(3 columns visible)

The downside of this however is that your final column must be the width of the logo, and must never be hidden, otherwise the logo will disappear.

**Summary**

These are the only workarounds I can think of.  Hopefully one is suitable for you.  As mentioned at the top SSRS really doesn't like dynamic layouting of objects!